# Can't see my device of chrome://inspect/#devices

Tags: android, google-chrome, inspect

I've followed the instructions at google: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging. I've also went over the troubleshooting section - but nothing seems to work.

I have samsung galaxy 3 (android 4.1.2, chrome 42.0.2311.111). USB debugging enabled. I've tried restarting the device after ticking the USB debugging a few times.

On windows 8 I run chrome (44.0.2388.0 canary). I've installed [Samsung USB Driver](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows), and my computer can see my device.

I do not get any notification when plugging the device nor when opening canary with the inspect page.
Did I miss anything?

Comment: if you open the command prompt and execute `adb devices`, your device is listed?

Comment: I do not have "adb", so I get "adb is not recognized...". it's written all over the place the adb is now a part of chrome... do I need to install anything beyond chrome?

Comment: No, you don't need it to debug with Chrome. It's only a fast way to check if your pc correctly see your device. If you open Device manager in Windows, with your device connected, every peripheral is correctly installed?

Comment: Yea - I've checked the Device Manager and it says that the driver is up to date etc.

Comment: I can see the device in windows device manager. I can browse the files. I can do everything one wants with the phone - except remote debugging - chrome just don't recognize it.

Comment: I have the same issue in Chrome Flatpak on Linux with Android 13 phone. Natively installed platform-tools work perfectly, but this doesn't.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try these steps:

- Download and install [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other)
- Open `SDK Manager.exe`
- Select `Android SDK Platform-tools` and press `Install packages...`
- Open a command prompt and execute these commands:

  - `cd C:\Program Files(x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools` (or `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`)
  - `adb.exe devices`

You should receive a response like this:

```
List of devices attached
ABCDEFG123  device
```

If your device is listed check if Chrome detect the device, otherwise try to execute this command:

- `adb.exe kill-server`
- `adb.exe start-server`
- `adb.exe devices`

Check again if Chrome detect the device.

If your device is not listed at all after executing `adb devices` command there is something wrong in your configuration (e.g. incorrect or missing drivers?)

Comment: Thanks. I've finally made it using a Nexus device. The samsung G3 just wouldn't talk to Chrome.

Comment: Sorry, but I followed all your steps. There is no Install packages, it just says Installed. There is also no android-sdk folder. There is only Android Studio and there is no platform-tools folder anywhere.

Comment: @Roger, this information is a bit out of date. Try here to download Platform Tools: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html

Comment: I have done all the steps, and I can successfully see my device on `adb devices` however I cannot see it in Chrome Dev Tools. Any guesses why this might be?

Comment: This worked after I turned off MySQL Server and then started adb.

Comment: Worked for me. Even though I regularly build Android apps, the adb.exe was not running or had crashed.

Comment: The platform tools are in another place for me: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`

Comment: Thanks !! this did the trick ! was stuck for a long time on this

Comment: Just ran "adb.exe devices" in run prompt. Now its working.

Answer (score 9):

In my case the problem was solved changing the usb connection mode in the settings of the Android device to **"Camera (PTP)"** . For some reason the usb debbuging did not work when connection mode was set to MTP.

Comment: That was the solution for me, with my Samsung Galaxy S8. The accepted answer did not work for me.

Comment: This was my issue on a Lenovo Tablet

Comment: What also worked for me was just waiting 5-10 minutes. It would never connect instantly but wait 5-10 minutes and it usually appears. keep it on PTP mode as well just to be safe.

Answer (score 8):

Hope this helps somebody else...

This happened to me because I was trying to Chrome inspect a release build (Ionic; i.e. `ionic build android --release`). If I build a debug app (`ionic build android`), I am able to see the app from the chrome inspection tool without any issues.

Google play does not like debugable apps https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/index.html
 which is needed for the inspection - see this SO link: [debugging an ionic app for android platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175926/debugging-an-ionic-app-for-android-platform) hence proper releases won't appear in the Chrome inspection.

Comment: Thank you!
My issue was not exactly the same as that of the OP, but my googling brought me here, and you had the correct answer.  

For me to change to a non-release version was a matter of taking `android:debuggable="false"` out of the `<application>` tag of my `AndroidManifest.xml` before re-running `$ cordova run android`.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in Chrome or in Android. This helped me: on your android device select USB connection settings (popup which is open on cable connect). It has MTP/PTP/charge modes. Switch between MTP/PTP and back.

Answer (score -2):

Download and install Android SDK

Open SDK Manager.exe

Select Android SDK Platform-tools and press Install packages...

MTP -> PTP