# why my phonegap app cannot be inspected by chrome inspector?

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, phonegap-build, inspector

I'm building cordova apps using the phonegap build tool, but i can't debug it.
If I go to *chrome inspect*, I cannot see my application, even though I enabled the debug mode on my android phone and i already opened my app.

Comment: What Android version is your phone on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983673/cant-see-my-device-of-chrome-inspect-devices might be of interest...

Comment: the phone is on Marshmellow, but as i already said, the app is an hybrid app built with apache cordova

Comment: Thank you phonolog, but none of the steps written in there has been helpful :(